# Customing uikit.modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, uikit

I'm developping an application and i want to open a large modal.

```
UIkit.modal.confirm('html content', function(){ myFunction() });
```

In this way it generates a default modal.

```
<div class="uk-modal-dialog" style="min-height:0;"><div>
```

But i want that generates to me a modal with 80% width or a large modal. like this for exemple :

```
<div class="uk-modal-dialog" style="min-height:0; width:80%"><div>
```

> what i have to do?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Check this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/cubttgow/28/

Comment: i'm using the function UIkit.modal.confirm() that generates the modal. so i have to add on it something to make her generating a large modal by just adding width:80% on style attribute

Comment: UIkit is an IOS library ?

Comment: Check this to: https://jsfiddle.net/Greggg/qjcLad46/

Comment: No, check this https://getuikit.com/docs/modal#javascript

Comment: there is no way to customise it on UIkit.modal.confirm() function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142262/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-ld91).

Answer (score 0):

In UIKIT version 2 you can do this :

```
const $modal= UIkit.modal.confirm(COMBINEDMSGTEXT,
    function () {
       //ur costom code
    }, {
    labels: {
        "Cancel": "Text",
        "Ok": "Text"
    }
  });
//if you console log $modal you will notice you have access to selector and element
const el = $modal.element; // this will return the main selector with the class uk-open 
el.children().css("width", "52%"); // the right div you need to target is actually a child element.
```

In UIKIT 3 , just use directly modal.$el and you will access the seletor wanted.